# Accessing outer class properties

Tags: javascript

How can I access outer class properties in JavaScript?

For example:

```
var outer = {
    outerField: 15,
    inner: {
        innerFunc: function () {
            // <-- How can I get access to outerField here?
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The lazy way is to do `outer.outerField`.

Answer (score 0):

This (answered) question is similar, you basically define an inner's object method from the outer object to get properties from the outer object: [access javascript parent class properties from subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531745/access-javascript-parent-class-properties-from-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution worked**

```
    var outer = {
    outervalue: 3,
    inner: {
        innerFunc: function () {
            // How can I get access to outer_value inside this method       
                    return (this.outervalue);
        }.call(outer)
    }
};
```