# How to access the parent class properties from a subclass?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about Javascript objects. How can I access the properties of the parent class?

```
function randomObj() // for example button obj
{
    this.text = "this is obj";
}

function parentClass()
{
    this.name = "parent";
    this.subObj;
}

parentClass.prototype.generate = function()
{
    this.subObj = new randomObj();
    this.subObj.changeParentClassName = function() // button obj wants to change name
    {
        this.name = "not parent";
    }
}

var sampleObj = new parentClass();
sampleObj.generate();
sampleObj.subObj.changeParentClassName (); // does not works
```

It seems 'this' in 'changeParentClassName' is subObj, how can I access parentclass.name?

Comment: Skip the `new` before the `function () { ... }` expression. It's using the `function` as a constructor to immediately create an instance.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski sry I typo when write this question.. thx anyways ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript's `this` will be the object to the left of the `.` when calling the function.  In this case, it is the subObj not the parentObj so you are setting `name` on subObj.  You have 2 options, you can put `this` in a different variable inside `generate` so it doesn't get replaced by JavaScript's `this` logic.  Something like:

```
var parentObj = this;
this.subObj.changeParentClassName = function() // button obj wants to change name
{
    parentObj.name = "not parent";
};
```

Or you can use the bind() to create a new function that will have `this` bound to a known object (in this case your parent object)  Something like:

```
this.subObj.changeParentClassName = (function() // button obj wants to change name
{
    this.name = "not parent";
}).bind(this); // bind the 'this' inside the changeParentClassName to the 'this' inside generate
```

Check out [Function bind()](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) for more info on bind and interactive examples.

Note, if you are targeting a recent version of Javascript (ECMAScript 6 or later), you can use a `=>` function which does not change the value of `this` compared to the declaring scope.  So you could use:

```
this.subObj.changeParentClassName = () => // button obj wants to change name
{
    this.name = "not parent";
};
```